# Count Column Values With Range Specified - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In My SQL Query I Return Column with Difference Between GetDate() and Column Named "OriginalFaultOccuredOn" (DataType is DateTime).I have done some Converion so That it will show me diiference in Format Like 5.56 (5 Hours and 56 Minutes)

Result is Like

```
<Column Name>

3.45
5.55
1.23
10.65
```

I want to Modify it in Further Way that it Shud Print Result like

```
More Than 6 Hours  More THan 12 Hours More than 24 Hours
3                  5                  6
```

My SQL Query Look like:-

```
    Select Floor(Convert(Numeric(18,2),Convert(Numeric(18,2),DateDiff(MI, OriginalFaultOccurredOn, GetDate()))/60)) + 
Convert(Numeric(18,2),((Convert(Numeric(18,2),Convert(Numeric(18,2),DateDiff(MI, OriginalFaultOccurredOn, GetDate()))/60) -
Floor(Convert(Numeric(18,2),Convert(Numeric(18,2),DateDiff(MI, OriginalFaultOccurredOn, GetDate()))/60)))*0.6))[Time] 
From Ticket Where Closed=0
```

DataBase is MS-SQL Server

Comment: Just make use of [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the result you want. you can check link given over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might count occurrences that fall in specified range by adding one each time a match is found:

```
select sum(case when [time] > 6 and [time] <= 12 then 1 end) [More than 6 hours],
       sum(case when [time] > 12 and [time] <= 24 then 1 end) [More than 12 hours],
       sum(case when [time] > 24 then 1 end) [More than 24 hours]
from
(
 { your-query-here }
) a
```